# ipod 4th gen wont load app

Tags: ios, ios5

Ive tested my app on the iphone 3GS+, and all the ipads and it just gives me a black screen after the loading screen is done. Its an openGL ES app, and after buying one here is the stack trace. Anyone know what is the problem?

```
0 Husky Bus Free 0x001950da + 0
1 Husky Bus Free 0x00195d04 + 0
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32a0b7ec _sigtramp + 48
3 libGPUSupportMercury.dylib 0x37c360b4 gpus_KillClient + 24
4 libGPUSupportMercury.dylib 0x37c365c0 gpusSubmitDMABuffers + 136
5 IMGSGX543GLDriver 0x3396e536 SubmitPacketsIfAny + 158
6 IMGSGX543GLDriver 0x3396e65a glrFlushContextToken + 38
7 GLEngine 0x34b4ec50 gliPresentViewES + 216
8 OpenGLES 0x358506ba -[EAGLContext presentRenderbuffer:] + 66
9 Husky Bus Free 0x000e72aa + 0
10 Foundation 0x3512360c __NSFireTimer + 144
11 CoreFoundation 0x355d3a32 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
12 CoreFoundation 0x355d3698 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 364
13 CoreFoundation 0x355d226e __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
14 CoreFoundation 0x355554a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
15 CoreFoundation 0x3555536c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
16 GraphicsServices 0x371f1438 GSEventRunModal + 136
17 UIKit 0x33061cd4 UIApplicationMain + 1080
18 Husky Bus Free 0x000e666c + 0
19 Husky Bus Free 0x000e1393 + 0
```

Comment: Methinks you have a renderBuffer problem.  Have you run it through instruments yet?

Comment: i commented out the GLView and its crashing, and the debugger is saying it cant get the process. Even when launching it normally i see the loading screen and the app goes right to black.

Comment: Can't get the process?  Like hanging and not _attaching_ the process, or is there some serious error message?

Comment: when i try debugging it cant get the process and doesnt attach. When i try to launch it from the home screen i just get the loading screen and after a couple seconds just black

Comment: Kill the simulator ***and its daemon*** in the activity monitor and restart your Mac.  The sim has all kinds of problems.

Comment: i just fixed that problem, investigating the black screen of death right now.

Comment: I still think it's a renderBuffer issue.  Run a zombies analysis.